Make a Texture3D writeable on the GPU in Unity
I have a Texture3D that I've defined:
tex = new Texture3D(8, 8, 8, TextureFormat.RFloat, false);

for (int x = 0; x < 8; x++) {
    for (int y = 0; y < 8; y++) {
        for (int z = 0; z < 8; z++) {
            if (x == 0 || y == 0 || z == 0 || x == 7 || y == 7 || z == 7) {
                points_f[z * 8 * 8 + y * 8 + x] = -1000.0f;
            } else {
                points_f[z * 8 * 8 + y * 8 + x] = 1.0f;
            }
        }
    }
}

tex.SetPixelData<float>(points_f, 0);
tex.Apply();

I'm binding it to a shader:
shader.SetTexture (0, "points", tex);

Inside of that shader I would like to write to the points inside of tex.
I've defined the Texture3D as a RWTexture3D in HLSL:
RWTexture3D<float> points;

However, when I run it I get this error:
Property (points) at kernel index (0): Attempting to bind texture as UAV but the texture wasn't created with the UAV usage flag set!
It's complaining that the UAV flag isn't set for the Texture3D - I haven't been able to find any method of making this writeable.
I would like this to be a Texture3D whose data exists entirely on the GPU because I don't need the points in RAM and all calculations are done on the GPU. I'd rather not transfer the points to the GPU every time we want to do some modification to them.
Thank you!

You may want to use a RenderTexture instead. Those are writable by the GPU.

Thank you, that's the correct answer :)
For anyone seeing this in the future, a couple of pitfalls are:
1 - Don't set the depth in the constructor, instead set it using RenderTexture.volumeDepth.
2 - For setting data on the GPU, Graphics.Blit doesn't work - instead you'll want to create a shader that writes the data into the RenderTexture.
3 - You need to set RenderTexture.dimension to UnityEngine.Rendering.TextureDimension.Tex3D and RenderTexture.enableRandomWrite to true otherwise the shader will refuse it as a RWTexture3D
